# How to make an input ( 84 23 75 24) into an array?

Tags: java

I won't have any code to put here since this is the start of it. But I would be asking for the input of numbers that will be inputted like this "75 69 35 95 90 45 66"
What do I do with the input to turn it into an array, I know how to scan it and turn it into string but that's about it.

Comment: 1) Read the line into a string, 2) parse the string into numbers, and 3) store the numbers into a Java array.  For steps 2) and 3) consider Java[String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Comment: An array of what? `int[]`, `Integer[]`, `List<Integer>`, `String[]`, `List<String>`? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample code that makes "explode" the string. Each item is then converted to integer.

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String[] ss = "75 69 35 95 90 45 66".split(" ");
for (String s: ss) {
  l.add(Integer.valueOf(s));
}
System.out.println(l);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the input is a proper integer.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while(in.hasNextInt()) {
  arrayList.add(in.nextInt());
}
System.out.println(arrayList);
```

If the input is a string

```
String str[] = "75 69 35 95 90 45 66".split(" ");
        
int len = str.length;
int numbers[] = new int[len];
int index = 0;
while(len > 0) {
  try {
    numbers[index] = Integer.parseInt(str[index]);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // something to do
  }
  System.out.println(numbers[index]);
  index++;
  len--;
}
```